# New Entries only showing on App Reload - CoreData and SwiftUI with MVVM

Tags: core-data, mvvm, swiftui

Working with a dummy project to learn more about Core Data in SwiftUI using MVVM. Print statements show that object is being saved, but the new entry doesn't show unless the app is restarted. Deleted objects are removed right away. So don't know where I am going wrong to have the new entries showing up right away. I guess I could re-call fetchTasks after every save, but don't know how to go about that as fetch tasks is in the TaskListViewModel, should I move fetch tasks to the CoreDataHandler?

**Entry**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestCore: App {
    
    //Inject Core Data container managed object context into environment
    let coreDataHandler = CoreDataHandler.shared
    
    //Optional: Add property to monitor scene phase
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            //Attach Core Date view context
            TaskListView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, coreDataHandler.container.viewContext)
        }
        //Whenver the app is moved to the background CoreDataUtility save() function is called to save any changes
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { _ in
            coreDataHandler.save()
        }
    }
}
```

**CoreDataHandler.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

struct CoreDataHandler {
    //Create a singleton to be used/shared throughout app
    static let shared = CoreDataHandler()
    
    //Create the storage container for Core Data
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    //MARK: - Test Configuration for SwiftUI Previews
    //Create a test configuration for SwiftUI Previews
    static var preview: CoreDataHandler = {
        let handler = CoreDataHandler(inMemory: true)
        
        //Create example task entries
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let task = Task(context: handler.container.viewContext)
            task.title = "Untitled Task"
            task.dateCreated = Date()
            task.dateDue = Date()
            task.completed = false
            task.archived = false
        }
        
        return handler
    }()
    
    //MARK: - Initializer to Load Core Data
    //Create an initializer to load Core Data, optionally able to use in-memory store
    //TODO: PRE-LAUNCH - Change inMemory back to false
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        //Point the NSPersistentContainer to the Data Model
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestCore")
        
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)!")
            } else {
                print("SUCCESS: Successfully loaded Core Data")
            }
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - Core Data Interactions
    func save() {
        let context = container.viewContext
        
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print("ERROR: Unable to save to Core Data!")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

**TaskListView.swift** - Responsible for displaying tasks

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct TaskListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var coreDataHandler
    @StateObject var viewModel = TaskListViewModel()
    
    @State var showAddTaskView = false
    @State var dismissView = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(viewModel.taskList) { task in
                        //TODO: Load in Custom Task View
                        TaskCardView(taskTitle: task.title ?? "No Title")
                            .toolbar {
                                EditButton()
                            }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: viewModel.deleteTask)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        showAddTaskView = true
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Add Task")
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 60)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .cornerRadius(30)
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showAddTaskView, content: {
                        AddTaskView()
                    })
                }
            }
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Tasks")
        .onAppear(perform: viewModel.fetchTasks)
        
    }
}
```

**TaskListViewModel**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

final class TaskListViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    var coreData = CoreDataHandler.shared
    @Published var taskList : [Task] = []
    
    init() {
        fetchTasks()
    }
    
    func fetchTasks() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Task>(entityName: "Task")
        do {
            taskList = try coreData.container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("ERROR: Error fetching tasks for TaskListView - \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func deleteTask(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        guard let index = indexSet.first else { return }
        let task = taskList[index]
        coreData.container.viewContext.delete(task)
        //Save change to Core Data
        coreData.save()
        //Fetch tasks to refresh taskList
        fetchTasks()
    }
}
```

**AddTaskView.swift** - Responsible for adding tasks

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddTaskView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var coreDataHandler
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @StateObject var viewModel = AddTaskViewModel()
    @StateObject var taskListViewModel = TaskListViewModel()
    
    @State var titleTextFieldText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                TextField("Task Title", text: $titleTextFieldText)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .frame(height: 55)
                    //TODO: Update to a specific color
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.addTask(taskTitle: titleTextFieldText, taskDueDate: Date()) 
                    //Dismiss View if successful
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Add Task")
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 60)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                        .cornerRadius(30)
                })
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Create New Task")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
    }
}
```

**AddTaskViewModel.swift**

```
import Foundation

final class AddTaskViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    var coreDataHandler = CoreDataHandler.shared
    
    func addTask(taskTitle: String, taskDueDate: Date) {
        let newTask = Task(context: coreDataHandler.container.viewContext)
        
        newTask.title = taskTitle;
        newTask.dateCreated = Date();
        newTask.dateDue = taskDueDate;
        newTask.completed = false
        newTask.archived = false
        
        coreDataHandler.save()
    } 
}
```

[image: Task Entity from TestCore.xcdatamodeld file]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, your model’s fetchTasks() function is only called once, when the model first loads. You’d need to call it every time the data changes if you want to get the latest data. You could do this easily by watching for NSManagedObjectContext.didSaveObjectsNotification, which is called any time the database is updated.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import Combine

final class TaskListViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    var coreData = CoreDataHandler.shared
    @Published var taskList : [Task] = []
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        fetchTasks()

        cancellable = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSManagedObjectContext.didSaveObjectsNotification, object: nil)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
            self.fetchTasks()
        })
    }

    ...
```

That said, there are better options than calling fetchTasks() all the time. Look into using @FetchRequest in your view, or using NSFetchedResultsController, which automatically updates itself, in your model.

Here’s a nice look at the options: https://www.donnywals.com/responding-to-changes-in-a-managed-object-context/

Comment: That is where I got a bit confused about how to call fetchtasks() from the view, as the taskList is in the TaskListViewModel?

The article was a little bit confusing to understand. I Will take a look at using @FetchRequest though

Comment: Don’t call fetchTasks from the view. In the model, you would create an NSFetchedResultsController, or you could observe that notification I mentioned there.

Comment: fwiw been down the MVVM path and don't use it anymore; very much agree with @Adam - better to us `@FetchResults` to inject data into dumb/pure layout views. However, if you'd like to  take a peak at an example that does pretty much what you're after alongside the `@FetchResults` alternative have a look at my demo project over here https://github.com/shufflingB/swiftui-core-data-with-model

Comment: @nix.codes I added a code sample for the simple NSManagedObjectContext.didSaveObjectsNotification solution. However, I would still recommend the NSFetchedResultsController solution for MVVM — your `taskList` array is somewhat risky, especially if you end up with a large dataset or a more complex model. Here's another NSFetchedResultsController example, if it helps: https://cargath.github.io/blog/2019/06/25/SwiftUI-NSFetchedResultsController